# Convergence in Probability (weak law of large numbers)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d. standard normal
random variables. Prove that

$$\frac{X_1X_2 + X_2X_3 + X_3X_4 + \cdots + X_{n−1}X_n}{n}$$

converges in probability to 0.

I started this by taking letting Y equal the above expression and taking the expectation of Y, which is 0.  Now I am stuck.

Comment: why is this question "off topic"?

Comment: This is explained in the frame starting by "put on hold as off-topic by".

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_k = X_kX_{k+1}$ where the $X_k$ are iid standard normal random variables.

Then

$$E(Y_k) = E(X_k)E(X_{k+1})=0, \\ var(Y_k) = E(Y_k^2) = E(X_k^2)E(X_{k+1}^2)=1.$$

Also

$$var\left(n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}Y_k\right) = E\left(n^{-2} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}X_jX_{j+1}X_kX_{k+1} \right) \\=n^{-2} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E(X_jX_{j+1}X_kX_{k+1}).$$

Since the $X_k$ are independent only $n-1$ terms ($E(X_j^2X_{j+1}^2)=1$) in the double sum are non-zero and

$$var\left(n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}Y_k\right) = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$$

By Chebyshev's inequality

$$ P(|\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} Y_k| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{n-1}{n^2\epsilon^2}.$$

For all $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} Y_k| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$

Comment: The $Y_k$'s are not independent so there will be some covariance. The same idea works though.

Comment: @Alex R:  Thanks.  I realize they are not independent but the variance of $\sum Y_k$ is the expectation of a double sum and the expectation of overlap terms $X_kX_{k+1}^2X_{k+2}$ is zero.

Comment: Whoops! Good point!

Comment: There is a massively simpler approach.

Comment: Hint: (Weak) LLN for sums of i.i.d. random variables, *twice*.

Comment: @Did can you give more of a hint?  I re-edited my question.